# How can I use PHP POST Variables on an app.js page that does not require reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

IK am attempting to make a web-based app for use on mobile devices. I used Code Kik's app.js for a simple setup but I am unsure how to proceed with the below.

The app opens on a home page where the user can enter players for a gap. Upon starting the game I want all of the player names to be stored in an array.

This is my HTML amd JavaScript with the proper app load lines and a jquery mechanism for adding and subtracting players. As you will see I added name=" title[]" to each input hoping to store them to a POST Variable called title but I cannot access this array from the 'game' Page. I am not sure how to proceed. I am very new to all of these languages and Stack Overflow So I apologize in advance if any of this is confusing or has been asked before. Thanks so much in advanced.

```
   <div class="app-page" data-page="home">
        <nav style="text-align:center !important;" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
          <a class="navbar-brand"><span class="addPad">Drinkr</span><i class="fas fa-wine-glass-alt"></i><i class="fas fa-glass-martini"></i> <i class="fas fa-beer"></i></a>
         
        </nav>
        <div class="wrapper h-100 w-100">

            <div class="container h-100 d-flex">
               
               <div class="jumbotron mx-auto">
                
                    <h1 class="display-4 text-white dat-font">Welcome</h1>
                    
                    <form>
                     
                        <div class="form-group">
                    
                            <p class="lead text-white">Please enter each player's name below</p>
                                                        
                            
                        </div>
                    
                    
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <div id="inputFormRow">
                                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                        <input type="text" name="title[]" class="form-control m-input iAmHere" placeholder="Your Name Here" autocomplete="off">
                                        <div class="input-group-append">                
                                            <button id="removeRow" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Kick Em Out</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div id="newRow"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                                    <button id="addRow" type="button" class="btn btn-success my-2 my-sm-0 col"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i>Player</button>
                                    <button id="letsGo" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0 col"><i class="fas fa-play"></i>Get Drunk!</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    
               </div>

            </div>
            
        </div>
    
    </div>
    
    <div class="app-page" data-page="game">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><span class="addPad">Drinkr</span><i class="fas fa-wine-glass-alt"></i><i class="fas fa-glass-martini"></i> <i class="fas fa-beer"></i></a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              
            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
              <button id="inGameAddPlayer" class="btn btn-success my-2 my-sm-0"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i>Add Player</button>
              <button id="stopGame" class="btn btn-danger my-2 my-sm-0"><i class="fas fa-stop"></i>End Game</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="wrapper h-100 w-100">

            <div class="container h-100 d-flex">
               
               <div class="jumbotron mx-auto">
                
                    <p class="players"></p>
                
                </div>
            
            </div>
            
        </div>
        
    </div>
 <script src="zepto.js"></script>
    <script src="app.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>

App.load('home');
        
    // add row
    $("#addRow").click(function () {
        if ($('.iAmHere').length < 10) { 
            var html = '';
            html += '<div id="inputFormRow">';
            html += '<div class="input-group mb-3">';
            html += '<input type="text" name="title[]" class="form-control m-input iAmHere" placeholder="Your Name Here" autocomplete="off">';
            html += '<div class="input-group-append">';
            html += '<button id="removeRow" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Kick Em Out</button>';
            html += '</div>';
            html += '</div>';

            $('#newRow').append(html);
        
        } else {
        
            $("#addRow").addClass("d-none");
        
        }
    });

    // remove row
    $(document).on('click', '#removeRow', function () {
        $(this).closest('#inputFormRow').remove();
        $("#addRow").removeClass("d-none");
    });
    
    $("#letsGo").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        App.load('game');
        $("#stopGame").click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            App.load('home');
            
            });
        
        $("#inGameAddPlayer").click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            
            
            });
        
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to StackOverflow. This site is geared more for questions stated as "what did I do wrong?" than it is for questions as "how do I do this?".  It's really up to you to learn how, and if something doesn't work then the community here looks at what you tried.

That being said, please take a look into the [JQuery post()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) method, as it's probably what you're looking for.

```
$("button").click(function(){
      $.post("demo_test.php", function(data, status){
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
      });
});
```